# Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS System Freezes when AVD is launching

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, ubuntu-18.04, android-virtual-device

Memory : 15,5 Gib
Processor : Intel® Core™ i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz × 12
Graphics : GeForce GTX 980 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
GNOME : 3.28.2
OS type : 64-bit
Disk : 61,3GB

Android studio 4.1.1

I tried the solution proposed by this [ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS crashes when starting android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584765/ubuntu-16-04-1-lts-crashes-when-starting-android-emulator), but I don't have the option to set the performance "no automatic"
Thanks for your help.

Comment: try it with software or hardware graphic option

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011575/android-emulator-crashes-with-sigsegv-on-ubuntu-18-04